# Rails - stop a form being created with IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Following Michael Harvati's rails tutorial. We create a form, but by default rails seems to render it with ID's. How do you stop a form being rendered with ID's for each element?

The Rails code:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the presence of the ID on the `form` tag causing a problem?

Comment: It prevents me from creating multiple forms on the same page for the same model (imagine a wall of photos, each one has a comment form... now I've got more than 1 element with an identical ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked how to remove the ID attribute from the rendered form, however using the clarification given in your comment, it sounds like what you really have is an example of a nested resource. So, I'll post an answer that addresses this, rather than your original question, and hopefully it might help.

I'll use your example: if a user is able to post a comment on an image, then your route might be set up to look something like this:

```
resources :image do
    resources :comment
end
```

In your form, lets assume you have multiple images being rendered, it might look something like this:

```
<% @images.each do |image|
    ... image stuff goes here ...

    <%= form_for [image, @comment] do |image_form|
        ... comment form stuff goes here ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will be rendered to the controller in a params hash that should look something like this:

```
{
    "image_id"=>"42",
    "comment"=>{...comment form attributes...}
}
```

If I'm completely off and have totally misunderstood you, let me know.

Answer (score -2):

Try `form_for(@user), html: {:id => nil}`

Comment: This will also **not** change the ID attributes of the input fields either.

Comment: probably because of the ruby1.9+ syntax

Comment: Anyway I misunderstood your question. For text_field/password_field/etc you can add a `:id => nil` as options (ex: `<%= f.text_field :name, :id => nil %>` and it will fix your problem.

Comment: @bcd, This will set default id instead of blank.